# Webview terminates my application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using C# and Windows Phone 8.1 (as Universal). I have a `WebView` using this code:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```

I load an HTML string or URI but when I scroll or tap on `WebView` it terminates my Application.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: First of all, you check whether there's any exception being thrown?

Comment: No, just terminates the app. I ran on my phone directly by Visual Studio. and it just terminates without anything

Comment: @WindowsPhoneDev are you having any tap event for the `WebView`?

Comment: Nope. As you see on my code, I didn't set anything